# I Can't Map Data in Array

Tags: arrays, reactjs, dictionary

Sorry for my English is not very good. I'm learning React. I'm going to make a todo app. I want the 'input' content to appear as h4 when I press the button. But I can't map. Where do you think is the mistake?

```
import "./App.css";
import { useRef, useState } from "react";

function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState([]);

  const inp = useRef(null);

  const Add = () => {
    setState([...state, inp.current.value]);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input name="inp" ref={inp} />
      <button onClick={Add}>Add</button>
      {state.map((e) => {
        <h4>{e}</h4>;
      })}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this

```
return (
    <div className="App">
      <input name="inp" ref={inp} />
      <button onClick={Add}>Add</button>
      {state.map((e) => {
        <h4>{e}</h4>;
      })}
    </div>
  );
```

into this

```
return (
    <div className="App">
      <input name="inp" ref={inp} />
      <button onClick={Add}>Add</button>
      {state.map((e) => {
       return (
           <h4>{e}</h4>;
)
      })}
    </div>
  );
```

You forgot to return the element in map.

There are two ways of doing it.

```
// 1

 array.map((el) => ( <div>{el}</div> ))
// 2

 array.map((el) => { return <div>{el}</div> })
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked. But there was already one. Why did I have to write another 'return'?

Comment: @arthurFleck Because you're using arrow function with curly braces `{ }`. They form a block. You need to use `return` to make function return something. As I've mentioned above, there is another option where you don't need to explicitly write `return`.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is in `inp.current.value` you need to change it to

```
 const Add = (evt) => {
   var val = evt.target.value;
    setState([...state, val]);
  };
```

let me know if it work